# How restrict internet use by AD group - ISA Server alternatives

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, proxy

I help out at an after school project and we are trying to ban a certain group from youtube.com.

They are (or can be) in a specific Active Directory group and we are running Windows Server 2003.

ISA Server costs around $1600, which is probably a bit much for the current budget.  Does anyone know of an alternative that will let us filter sites by AD groups?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the good old well known Squid proxy for this.

[Here](http://klaubert.wordpress.com/2008/01/09/squid-kerberos-authentication-and-ldap-authorization-in-active-directory/) is just one howto with config examples. Google will give you a lot more in no-time.

HTH,
PEra

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Untangle](http://www.untangle.com/).  You would have to purchase Active Directory integration, but it's not expensive.  You'd also need a spare box to throw it on...so it basically becomes your edge router.  It'll do firewall, web filtering, virus scanning, etc out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

use a router which support URL filtering. Draytek is a good low cost example.